# C# Oledb truncando coluna excel

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, microsoft-access, oledb

Estou realizando um select em um excel onde tenho uma coluna observação (texto aberto). O problema é que em algumas linhas ele trunca o conteúdo dessa coluna trazendo apenas uma parte.

```
try
{
    conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Path.Combine(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%userprofile%"), "Downloads") + @"\RelPosicaoGeralPendencias.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;'");
    conn.Open();

    cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [RelPosicaoGeralPendencias$]", conn);

    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    listaPendenciaNassau = new List<Pendencia>();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (!(reader[6] is DBNull))
        {
            Pendencia pendencia = new Pendencia();

            pendencia.Contrato = reader[2] is DBNull ? null : reader[2].ToString().Replace("'", "").Trim();
            pendencia.Tipo = reader[3] is DBNull ? null : reader[3].ToString().Trim();
            pendencia.PendenciaNivel = reader[5] is DBNull ? null : reader[5].ToString().Trim();
            pendencia.PendenciaId = reader[6] is DBNull ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(reader[6]);
            pendencia.PendenciaTipo = reader[8] is DBNull ? null : reader[8].ToString().Trim();
            pendencia.GarantiaDescricao = reader[9] is DBNull ? null : reader[9].ToString().Trim();
            pendencia.Observacao = reader[10] is DBNull ? null : reader[10].ToString().Replace("'", "").Trim();
        }
    }
}
```

Exemplo de texto:

**No excel:**

As pendências permanecem. As autorizações encaminhadas são 2012 venceram e não estão de acordo com as regras atuais para que possamos acatar.

EMPRESA IMPORTACAO E EXPORTACAO LTDA .

Assinatura Fulano.

Pendência: Enviar autorização da maioria do capital social.

EMPRESA EXPORTAÇÃO E IMPORTAÇÃO LTDA.

Assinatura: Beltrano.

Pendência: Enviar autorização de 3/4 do capital social.
EMPRESA DE HORTIFRUTIGRANJEIROS LTDA

Assinatura: Cicrano.

Pendência: Enviar ata de autorização da maioria do capital social
EMPRESA PROD. E DISTRIBUIÇÃO AGRICOLA LTDA.

Assinatura: Fulano de Beltrano.

Pendência: Enviar contrato social vigente e procuração atribuindo poder de prestar aval a terceiros de forma isolada. Por favor, encaminhar a documentação societária para área de poderes.

**No c#:**

As pendências permanecem. As autorizações encaminhadas são 2012 venceram e não estão de acordo com as regras atuais para que possamos acatar.\n\n\nEMPRESA IMPORTACAO E EXPORTACAO LTDA .\n\nFulano.\n\nPendência: Enviar aut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Baseado nas informações do link abaixo, que diz que o driver do ODBC faz uma análise pelas 9 primeiras linhas de cada coluna para definir o tipo de dado da coluna, assim definindo com o Texto ao invés de Memorando, criei um mecanismo para inserir 320 cercadilhos a frente do texto da coluna observação e após efetuar o select no excel remover os cercadilhos.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/189897/data-truncated-to-255-characters-with-excel-odbc-driver